# Getting boolean value from object in array then assigning it a DOM property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, for-loop

For example:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "name": "grape",
      "fruit": false
    },
    {
      "name": "orange",
      "fruit": true
    }
  ]
}
```

I am looping through the array and putting them on the DOM with this:

```
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var item = '<li>'+data[i].name+'</li>';
    $('#list').append(item)
}
```

What I want to do is for every object in the array with the `fruit` value set to `true`, put `is a fruit` in the DOM, and vice versa.

How can I do this?

Comment: Perhaps with an `if` statement ?

Comment: "*put is a fruit in the DOM*" where?

Comment: I've tried that, both outside and inside the `for` loop, and it's not working for me.

Comment: @Taplar in the item variable next to the name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (var i=0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var fruitBool = data.fruit ? " is a fruit" : " is not a fruit";
    var item = '<li>' + data[i].name + fruitBool + '</li>';
    $('#list').append(item)
}
```

Comment: Is `fruitBool` a pun?  If so, I like it!

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways of doing this but basically this is the gist of it:

```js
// Initializing the data
const data = {
  data: [{
      "name": "grape",
      "fruit": false
    },
    {
      "name": "orange",
      "fruit": true
    }
  ]
}


// Getting the ul element
const ul = document.getElementById("list")


// Looping through the data array
data.data.forEach((item) => {

  // creating the listItem and assigning the text node
  const listItem = document.createElement('li')
  item.fruit ?
    listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode("The fruit " + item.name + " is a fruit")) :
    listItem.appendChild(document.createTextNode("The fruit " + item.name + " is not a fruit"));


  ul.appendChild(listItem)
})
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>
    Fruit checker
  </h1>
  <ul id="list"></ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data.forEach(function(element){
    var item = '<li>'+ element.name + (element.fruit ? ' is a fruit' : '') +'</li>';
    $('#list').append(item);
})
```

You can use a ternary to add the optional text if the value is true.

Answer (score -1):

You can use template literals. Secondly to access `data` you need to first access the object.

```js
let obj = {
  "data": [{
      "name": "grape",
      "fruit": false
    },
    {
      "name": "orange",
      "fruit": true
    }
  ]
}

let str = '';
let dt = obj.data;
for (var i = 0; i < dt.length; i++) {
  str += `<li>${dt[i].name}</li>`
}
document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = str
```

```html
<ul id='list'></ul>
```

Comment: what is the reason of downvoting?